# Android Custom GridView with Masonry Logic

Tags: android, performance, gridview, android-arrayadapter, android-custom-view

I'm quite new to the world of Android development, and I'm relatively comfortable working with Adapters and GridViews. However, I'm looking to build something a little more advanced with `GridView`s that seems to be proving quite difficult without using third-party libraries (impossible from what I've read). Even using a third-party library like Etsy StaggeredGridView (https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) I can't seem to get it right. The best I can get is having rows that bleed into other rows, Pinterest-style, but what I'd like is something along these lines:

[image: Android Custom GridView with Masonry Logic]

Where every `nth cell` actually has the width of two cells and offsets the grid.

So what I'd like some direction on is:

1. How could I accomplish this repeating pattern using a `GridView`/ `Adapter` combo?
2. Or failing that, how could I do this more efficiently than nesting a bunch of `LinearLayout`s inside a `ScrollView` and doing some really messy logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  `GridView` has no way of merging columns like that.  You can try using a [GridLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) or `TabletLayout` to obtain that look.  However neither support an adapter.  You're best bet is to look for 3rd party libraries.

If there isn't going to be a lot of scrollable content, I'd go with (Grid/Table)Layout. You may take a small hit with memory consumption but you'll save yourself a lot of time in implementing your own custom solution.  Which just may be your only choice if no 3rd party library exists.

One possibility would be to looking into [RecycleView](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html). It's a new view coming out with Android L that will also be in the support library. It's basically a more advanced version of a `ListView` that allows you to build customizable layouts that scroll and recycle their content. From the looks of it, it appears it would allow you to build an easy solution for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've looked at over a half dozen libraries and they all seem to be the same as the `StaggeredGridView` listed above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated my answer with further suggestions. In short, there aren't many options for ya.

Comment: `RecyclerView` looks fantastic! Thank you very much for this lead. I'm going to have a go with the support library and see what happens. Hopefully it will be what I'm after and I can mark this resolved.

Comment: I haven't had a lot of time to sit down and work this out fully,  but your answer is definitely the way to go. I thank you again, and I'll try to provide more information about the final solution in the near future for anyone else having this issue.